# How can I prevent my Ionic App from detecting missing peer dependencies in node_modules

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, dependencies, react-typescript, snappy

I have built a mobile app using Typescript React and Ionic. Using Appflow to deploy to a mobile device results in my build failing due to warnings regarding peer dependencies from MongoDB. I installed the peer dependencies, one of which is snappy - which has resulted in further missing dependencies that I cannot install due to them being platform specific. I have tried adding the node_modules file to my .eslintignore, but it still detects them as missing and due to the CI being set as treating warnings as errors, it breaks the build.

```
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.android-arm64.node' in 'D:\Projects\app\node_modules\snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.darwin-arm64.node' in 'D:\Projects\app\node_modules\snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.darwin-x64.node' in 'D:\Projects\app\node_modules\snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.freebsd-x64.node' in 'D:\Projects\app\node_modules\snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.linux-arm-gnueabihf.node' in 'D:\Projects\app\node_modules\snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.linux-arm64-gnu.node' in 'D:\Projects\app\node_modules\snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.linux-arm64-musl.node' in 'D:\Projects\app\node_modules\snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.linux-x64-gnu.node' in 'D:\Projects\app\node_modules\snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.linux-x64-musl.node' in 'D:\Projects\app\node_modules\snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.win32-arm64-msvc.node' in 'D:\Projects\app\node_modules\snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.win32-ia32-msvc.node' in 'D:\Projects\app\node_modules\snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve './snappy.win32-x64-msvc.node' in 'D:\Projects\app\node_modules\snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-android-arm64' in 'D:\Projects\app\node_modules\snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-darwin-arm64' in 'D:\Projects\app\node_modules\snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-darwin-x64' in 'D:\Projects\app\node_modules\snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-freebsd-x64' in 'D:\Projects\app\node_modules\snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-linux-arm-gnueabihf' in 'D:\Projects\app\node_modules\snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-linux-arm64-gnu' in 'D:\Projects\app\node_modules\snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-linux-arm64-musl' in 'D:\Projects\app\node_modules\snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-linux-x64-gnu' in 'D:\Projects\app\node_modules\snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-linux-x64-musl' in 'D:\Projects\app\node_modules\snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-win32-arm64-msvc' in 'D:\Projects\app\node_modules\snappy'
[react-scripts] ./node_modules/snappy/index.js
[react-scripts] Module not found: Can't resolve '@napi-rs/snappy-win32-ia32-msvc' in 'D:\Projects\app\node_modules\snappy'
```

this is the build result

[image: build result from appflow]

How can I either stop my Appflow CI from detecting this as an error, install the missing dependencies, or stop the warnings being returned from the node_modules file?

Answer (score 0):

The unresolved peer dependencies are still an issue, but I resolved the problem by disabling the CI in my build script by simply changing:

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
```

to:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "CI=false react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

in my package.json file. I still think that resolving the peer dependencies would have been a better solution, but this did the trick for now